# Cannot save keras model with custom layers to tf lite file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I want to port Mask-RCNN to tensorflow lite to be able to use it on my android device. Tensorflow lite has some tutorials showing how to do this, but their instructions fail when your model has a layer that extends the keras layer class. In particular, this is the error that I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
     87       module_objects=globs,
     88       custom_objects=custom_objects,
---> 89       printable_module_name='layer')

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    179     config = identifier
    180     (cls, cls_config) = class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(
--> 181         config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    182 
    183     if hasattr(cls, 'from_config'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    164     cls = module_objects.get(class_name)
    165     if cls is None:
--> 166       raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
    167   return (cls, config['config'])
    168 

ValueError: Unknown layer: ProposalLayer
```

The code that I  use to import the keras model is:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('mrcnn.h5')
```

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Keras-h5 saving only knows about standard layers.

There are three possible approaches for a fix here:

1) The [from_keras_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#from_keras_model_file) method has an argument called `custom_objects`. If your class correctly implements [get_config](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#you_can_optionally_enable_serialization_on_your_layers), and you pass it your class: `custom_objects={"ProposalLayer":my_layers.ProposalLayer}` it might just work.

Like how it's required to reload the model [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/hub_with_keras/)

2) An other option is to define your model using the [functional api](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/functional) which is better supported by the keras save and load.

3) If you can use a different file format: Try the [`save_format="tf"`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save) argument. The TensorFlow-SavedModel likely doesn't have this problem as it saves a lower level representation.

Comment: I tried the first solution you propose, but it complains about constructor arguments. This layer takes two positional arguments. I tried creating the object (with the right args) and then passing it into the map, but it still complains about the constructor params

Comment: For the 3rd solution you propose to work, the model should be a tf.keras.model, while mine is a keras.model file (the save method doesn't have that parameter)

Comment: Good points. I think you need to check the [get_config](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#you_can_optionally_enable_serialization_on_your_layers) method of your layer. AFAIK is needs to convert the args to json, and it's that json that's **unpacked to the constructor when the model is rebuilt. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
custom_objects={"ProposalLayer":ProposalLayer}
```